# How to get width and height of img tag not image itself

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get width and height of the img tag then i need asign them like:

```html
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

images.forEach(e => {
  // value = Get width and height of img tag
  
  // Asign this value to it like:
  
  // e.width = value
})
```

Comment: Why did you completely change the example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get its [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) and [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    console.log(images[i].offsetWidth, images[i].offsetHeight);
  }
})
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
```

Comment: could u look again